# Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore Causes my Xamarin Forms Android Project to Fail Deployment (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Google Firestore in my Xamarin forms app and after updating the Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore Nuget Package to the latest version, I am no longer able to debug my project on Android.

I made a new Xamarin Forms Project to first to check if the error was because of my code or because of an issue with the Nuget Package itself.

I then installed the Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore Nuget Package and quickly found that the problem wasn't with my code, it was with the Nuget Package.

If you are trying to install the Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore Nuget Package and you dont have the Xamarin.AndroidX.Core and Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser Nuget Packages installed, it will say "Could not add Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore" and show a really long error message. This is very annoying because it gives you a novel to read through instead of simply showing a prompt to install the Nuget Packages as dependencies alongside the parent Nuget Package.

Then in order to install the Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser Nuget Package, you first need to install the Xamarin.AndroidX.Core Nuget Package. If you don't install the Xamarin.AndroidX.Core Nuget Package first you will get another long error message saying that you need to install it.

After I install all three Nuget Packages and try to run my Android Project, I get this error message:

> /Users/{UserName}/Desktop/FirebaseTests/FirebaseTests/FirebaseTests.Android: Error JAVA0000: Error in /Users/{UserName}/.nuget/packages/xamarin.google.guava/31.1.0.3/buildTransitive/monoandroid12.0/../../jar/guava.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class:
> Type com.google.common.annotations.Beta is defined multiple times: /Users/{UserName}/.nuget/packages/xamarin.google.guava/31.1.0.3/buildTransitive/monoandroid12.0/../../jar/guava.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class, obj/Debug/lp/102/jl/__reference__guava.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class
> Compilation failed
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/{UserName}/.nuget/packages/xamarin.google.guava/31.1.0.3/buildTransitive/monoandroid12.0/../../jar/guava.jar
> com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:98)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.main(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:4)
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/{UserName}/.nuget/packages/xamarin.google.guava/31.1.0.3/buildTransitive/monoandroid12.0/../../jar/guava.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class
> at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.3.28.java:0)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:75)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:28)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:27)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.b(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:2)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:22)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:17)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:85)
> ... 1 more
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.f: Type com.google.common.annotations.Beta is defined multiple times: /Users/{UserName}/.nuget/packages/xamarin.google.guava/31.1.0.3/buildTransitive/monoandroid12.0/../../jar/guava.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class, obj/Debug/lp/102/jl/__reference__guava.jar:com/google/common/annotations/Beta.class
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.DT.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:14)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.DT.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:22)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.CN.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:33)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.CN.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:10)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.CN.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:6)
> at com.android.tools.r8.graph.B2$a.e(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:4)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:105)
> at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:28)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:25)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:606)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.c(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:1)
> at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Bj.a(R8_3.3.28_2aaf796388b4e9f6bed752d926eca110512a53a3f09a8d755196089c1cfdf799:24)
> ... 5 more
> Directory 'obj/Debug/lp/102' is from 'Xamarin.Grpc.Stub.dll'. (JAVA0000) (FirebaseTests.Android) java

The error refers to Xamarin.Google.Guava so I thought installing Xamarin.Google.Guava individually would solve the issue but not at all; I am still getting the same error.

Could someone please help me? There is no way I am the only person this is happening to.

Answer (score 0):

You should file the bug, `Xamarin.Firebase.Firestore` needs to work when installed: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/new

Aside from that you may try some older version and see if it works, e.g. version `123.0.3.7` seems to work well for me.